# Website vs. hosted Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, google-chrome-app

I'm pretty new in the field of Web Store and its content and I've been going through it for past few days. I am not sure if I'm getting it right, but as far as I know, Chrome Apps can be packaged or hosted and also I have noticed that both of them (packaged and hosted) will be removed from the Chrome Web Store on Windows, Mac and Linux.

But, [according to this page](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore), there are four types of content which can be published on Chrome Web Store - Websites, Chrome Apps, Extensions and Themes. And it somehow corresponds with the Web Store filters - you can filter between Websites and Chrome Apps.
And my question is - what is the difference between a Website and a hosted Chrome App? Is just Google messing up the terms (and by Website they mean hosted Chrome App and by Chrome App they mean packaged Chrome App) or is there any real difference?

Because this is what is totally confusing for me  - in the early 2018, when all the Chrome App stuff will be removed from any other OS than Chrome OS, what am I going to see if I open the Web Store on Windows? Themes and Extensions only? Or the Websites will be available too, because only Chrome Apps will not be supported and a Website is not a Chrome App?

And after the "early 2018", is there going to be any way how to integrate a Website to Chrome other than telling the users to manually bookmark it? It won't be possible to distribute a web app through the Web Store at all? Because what I also noticed is Google encouraging developers to create PWAs rather than Chrome Apps, but how those PWAs can be integrated to Chrome more smoothly than just a manually added bookmark?

Thank you very much for your answers and sorry for a long and chaotic post full of questions.
Karolina

Answer (score 0):

Gonna start by referencing the Wiki descriptions for a [Website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website):

> A website is a collection of related [web pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_page), including multimedia content, typically identified with a common [domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name), and published on at least one [web server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server). A website may be accessible via a public [Internet Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) (IP) network, such as the [Internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet), or a private [local area network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) (LAN), by referencing a [uniform resource locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) (URL) that identifies the site.

and a [Google Chrome App](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_App):

> A Google Chrome App is a [web application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application) that runs on the [Google Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) web browser. Chrome apps can be obtained from the [Chrome Web Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_Web_Store) where apps, [extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_extension), and themes can be installed or bought. There are two types of apps, hosted and packaged, which have different locations of their executable and are targeted at different use cases.

and for [Hosted Apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_App#Hosted_apps) part:

> Hosted apps are the original type of Chrome apps. They contain a single [manifest file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_file) that contains the URL and additional information about the app. Hosted apps are usually offline and are subject to regular web page security restrictions.

To say things simpler, a *Website* is such a broad term where in some cases, a *Hosted Web App* might actually fall under it's category.

While a Chrome Web App has this required *tie-in* with Google Chrome (hence it's name).

For more descriptions on the [difference between a Hosted and Packaged App (and an extension](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/apps_vs_extensions?csw=1#3types):

> There are actually two kinds of apps: hosted and packaged. A hosted app wraps an online website, so the CRX package can be as simple as a single manifest.json file pointing to the website. A packaged app contains the whole kit and kaboodle inside the CRX package—HTML, CSS, and so on, all run from the user’s hard drive.
>
> Packaged apps are a kind of missing link between extensions and hosted apps. They look the same as a hosted app to the user, but under the covers, they are really like traditional extensions with that special “launch” parameter. They have access to almost all functionality afforded to regular extensions—context menu, background pages, and so on. The only exception is that packaged apps can't add buttons to the address bar.
>
> Returning to the example in the previous section, it’s perfectly valid for a packaged app to add an item to Google Chrome's context menu. However, it’s completely invalid for a hosted app to do the same thing. In some respects, a packaged app lets you have your cake and eat it: the appearance of a packaged app with the power of an extension. But there are still plenty of reasons to use pure extensions and hosted apps.

Guide for choosing an App Type can be seen [here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/choosing).

---

For the *early 2018* part, there still isn't much details mentioned about it, but referring to the [Chromium blog](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html), I guess it's safe to say that the Chrome Web Apps will be totally removed (hence they're asking developers to [migrate their Chrome apps](https://developers.chrome.com/apps/migration) to the web) and that only extensions and themes would be available.

However, this could still be subject for change. At this point, no one could really tell.

Comment: I am sceptical about using the Wikipedia definition of a "website", because in this context it is about what the Chrome App Store platform calls 'Websites', which I think uses a different definition as evidenced by the fact that one can install offline 'Websites' that don't have a URL. According to my analysis Chrome Apps differ from Chrome Websites in not requiring an online counterpart and offering different features when they do have a counterpart. But in terms of javascript a Website can do the same as a hosted app.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] there are four types of content which can
>   be published on Chrome Web Store - Websites, Chrome Apps, Extensions
>   and Themes.

I'd say that is accurate.

- Some websites are just simple bookmarks you can find in the Chrome
  Store. I consider these little more than advertisements.
- Some websites do that and add trivial things like system
  notifications and even run offline. I.e. they have their code on your hard drive and access some system resources. But Google still categorises them as websites (or webapps in modern vernacular) probably because they have no special feature set. An example is Spotify or Gmail offline.
- Hosted Chrome apps might not have an online presence at all or typically do something different from the website version. For example, they could run in a specially designed transparent window; they may run offline too. An example is Hangouts, the app has slightly different features from the website at [hangouts.google.com](http://hangouts.google.com).
- Packaged Chrome apps are defined similarly, but need more access to system resources such as the filesystem. They are pushing the border of what we may define as being 'sandboxed'. They also may run offline. In some cases people who want to write scripts using javascript and html/css may consider this instead of a nodejs-like solution.

> what is the difference between a Website[/Webapp)] and a [...]Chrome
>   App?

Typically the ratio of 'fresh server code' to 'local drive code' gets smaller as you go down the above list, but this is just a correlation. The main difference between a Chrome app and a Web app is a unique content feature-set. Also webapps typically require at least periodic online contact, whereas a chrome app could just be a 100% offline game without an online counterpart.

> Is just Google messing up the terms [...] or is there any real
>   difference?

So yes according to how I see it there is a difference. Though personally, I'd categorise everything that puts code on your local drive as a chrome app and stuff that runs at least 99.9% online as a webapp/website. But Google disagrees apparently.

> in the early 2018, [...] what am I going to see if I open the Web
>   Store on Windows? Themes and Extensions only? Or the Websites will be
>   available too, because only Chrome Apps will not be supported and a
>   Website is not a Chrome App?

Only Google knows this I think. But I'm guessing you'll see Websites, and clicking "add to chrome" will create a bookmark for online stuff, or an extension for the offline stuff (like google docs). So you can distribute websites, you just won't be able to find them under an "Apps" panel. We'll also probably see an increase in extensions with a UI component as some apps are re-labelled as extensions.