# Will the Add-ons disappear and be useless for Google apps on 2017-2018?

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-apps-marketplace

I was trying to publish a new version of an Add-on that was already created, but when I tried to publish it, in the Developer Dashboard and on the top of the page a warning message was shown:

> As of November 21st, 2016, all newly published packaged or hosted apps are restricted to Chrome OS, and are not available to users on Windows, Mac or Linux. Existing apps will continue to be available on all major platforms and will continue to receive updates. - [More Info](http://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html)
>
> Note: This change does not apply to Google Drive Apps or Add-Ons for Google Apps.

So if you click on the "More Info" button you will see more additional information.

So all of this should be a problem to me because I have important applications that I need everyday, so I wonder if there is any other alternative way to keep working with add-ons.

Thank you!

Comment: *This change does not apply to ... Add-Ons for Google Apps* Not sure if on-topic here when you could ask Google about it

Comment: But I wonder if **Google Drive Apps** refers to Spreadsheet add-ons

Comment: And I asked Google but they didn't give me a solution, they told me to ask it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, this change (if Google decides to proceed with it) would only apply to [Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/apps_vs_extensions?csw=1) (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44023696/4625829)).

In the [Chromium Blogpost](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html) (also the link for *More Info* in your post), it mentioned:

> In the second half of 2017, the Chrome Web Store will no longer show Chrome apps on Windows, Mac, and Linux, but will continue to surface extensions and themes.

*Add-ons* weren't specifically mentioned, but as already included in your post, Add-ons that are for Google Drive Apps or any Google Apps in general (e.g. Docs, Sheets, etc.) are the exception.

If you're add-on is associated with a non-Google App, it is possible that you will be affected with the change. Seeing as the Chrome App will be removed, the associated Add-ons would follow.

You probably already know the differences between a Chrome App, an Extension, and an Add-on, but for future readers that are not familiar, might as well post this link to a YouTube video that explains [Apps vs Extensions vs Add-ons](https://youtu.be/2HkI0w9tUXQ).